Errors in npm i @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin command
I am trying to install eslint-plugin, but getting below shown error
    PS C:\Playwright> npm i @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin

npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: playwright@1.0.0
npm error Found: @typescript-eslint/parser@8.8.0
npm error node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser
npm error   @typescript-eslint/parser@"^8.8.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer @typescript-eslint/parser@"^4.0.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@4.33.0
npm error node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm error   @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^4.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error C:\\Users\\ShwetaTuli\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache_logs\\2024-10-04T06_33_43_179Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\\Users\\ShwetaTuli\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache_logs\\2024-10-04T06_33_43_179Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\\Playwright\>
-

The package-lock.json looks like below:
-

"node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc": {
"version": "3.1.0",
"resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@eslint/eslintrc/-/eslintrc-3.1.0.tgz",
"integrity": "sha512-4Bfj15dVJdoy3RfZmmo86RK1Fwzn6SstsvK9JS+BaVKqC6QQQQyXekNaC+g+LKNgkQ+2VhGAzm6hO40AhMR3zQ==",
"license": "MIT",
"dependencies": {
"ajv": "^6.12.4",
"debug": "^4.3.2",
"espree": "^10.0.1",
"globals": "^14.0.0",
"ignore": "^5.2.0",
"import-fresh": "^3.2.1",
"js-yaml": "^4.1.0",
"minimatch": "^3.1.2",
"strip-json-comments": "^3.1.1"
},
"engines": {
"node": "^18.18.0 || ^20.9.0 || \>=21.1.0"
},
"funding": {
"url": "https://opencollective.com/eslint"
}
},
"node_modules/@eslint/js": {
"version": "9.11.1",
"resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@eslint/js/-/js-9.11.1.tgz",
"integrity": "sha512-/qu+TWz8WwPWc7/HcIJKi+c+MOm46GdVaSlTTQcaqaL53+GsoA6MxWp5PtTx48qbSP7ylM1Kn7nhvkugfJvRSA==",
"license": "MIT",
"engines": {
"node": "^18.18.0 || ^20.9.0 || \>=21.1.0"
}
},
"node_modules/@eslint/object-schema": {
"version": "2.1.4",
"resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@eslint/object-schema/-/object-schema-2.1.4.tgz",
"integrity": "sha512-BsWiH1yFGjXXS2yvrf5LyuoSIIbPrGUWob917o+BTKuZ7qJdxX8aJLRxs1fS9n6r7vESrq1OUqb68dANcFXuQQ==",
"license": "Apache-2.0",
"engines": {
"node": "^18.18.0 || ^20.9.0 || \>=21.1.0"
}
},
"node_modules/@eslint/plugin-kit": {
"version": "0.2.0",
"resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@eslint/plugin-kit/-/plugin-kit-0.2.0.tgz",
"integrity": "sha512-vH9PiIMMwvhCx31Af3HiGzsVNULDbyVkHXwlemn/B0TFj/00ho3y55efXrUZTfQipxoHC5u4xq6zblww1zm1Ig==",
"license": "Apache-2.0",
"dependencies": {
"levn": "^0.4.1"
},
"engines": {
"node": "^18.18.0 || ^20.9.0 || \>=21.1.0"
}
},






Can you please help me to resolve above mentioned issues?
Thanks,
I tried couple of option given for the same issue on other page but still not able to resolve this issue.
I want to install this plugin and then need to Update Playwright to latest version (currently I am on 10.9.0)

This question is similar to: Unable to resolve dependency tree error when installing npm packages. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please see Why is "Can someone help me?" not a useful question?

When you are executing npm install @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin it looks for the version of this package in your package.json file and try to install this package with this version.
So you have @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin of v4.33.0 which is mentioned in the error logs. This version is an older version that requires an outdated @typescriopt-eslint/parser (in your case it's v8.8.0). So in other words the versions of these two packages are incompatible.
So just try to upgrade your @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin with
npm update @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin

or install the latest version of this package with:
npm install @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@latest

Another approach is to downgrade your @typescript-eslint/parser package to ^4.0.0 which is compatible with eslint-plugin@4.33.0 with:
npm install @typescript-eslint/parser@4.0.0

